# Put comma after a pattern in python regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, addition

Just like the question says I am trying to add a comma at the end of a pattern or sub string. I found 3 solutions that should do the job, and look logical too. But they are not changing anything. I will show you all those codes. The goal is to find out if there is something that I am missing or something I can add to make it work.

By the way, on Google most of these comma related questions are about adding comma in a number string at thousandth place, then 5th place etc. like this- 1,00,000. That is not what I am looking for.

So here are some of the codes I tried:

```
import re
f = open('pizza.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()



for x in content:
  regex = r"\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"
  rep_str = regex+","
  sentence += re.sub(regex, rep_str, x)
   
print(sentence)


content="42/20/2021 every day is a good day 30.25

13/14/2015 today is saturday 24."
```

Here I tried reading it line by line from a text file. The content variable at the bottom showing you what is inside the text file. Those are just test strings. Each string has a pattern for date, followed by some text mixed with numbers then a floating point.

Ideally I would like to put a comma right after the date and another one after the text and number mix, just before the floating point number.

To keep it simple I started by adding just the first comma after the date.

The variable regex has the pattern for date. The variable rep_str containing what I want the pattern to be replaced with, that is the pattern followed by a comma. Then re.sub to do the job. The output is the strings in the text files with no change. No comma nothing.

Next code:

```
content = "13/14/2015 today 001 is saturday 24.34"
m = re.sub(r'(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})(.*)', r'\1 ,\2 ', content)
   
print(m)
```

Even simpler, no text file, just 1 string. The code has 2 patterns. One for date, other one for everything else. Tried to add comma between them. Same result. No comma, no error, just the same string as output.

Third attempt:

```
content = "13/14/2015 today 001 is saturday 24.34"
result = re.sub('/(?<=\d\b)(?!,)/', ',', content); 
print(result)
```

This piece of code is collected from here. First part of the code looking for a alphanumeric that ends with a number with word boundaries. Next brace is confirming that there is not a comma already. Then place the comma. This code apparently  solved a similar problem I have. So I gave it a try. Surprisingly the result has been the same. No error, no change, same string as output.

If you spot anything or can think of a working code, do advise.

Comment: You match literal `\d` with `r'\\d'`, use `regex = r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"`. You also read the file into a single variable, so do not use for loop here, use just `content = re.sub(regex, rep_str, content)`. If you need to process line by line use `content = f.readlines()`

Comment: I tried the pattern with single slash, that's what my initial code was. Got this error :error: bad escape \d at position 0. So I changed as the system prompted. I am using jupyter notebook. Also tried the same code without  for loop. No luck. Thanks for your comment by the way.

Comment: Sorry to ask but is run the code snippet function new? I am seeing it for the first time.

Comment: You got that error because you did not use the raw string literal. You should either use a raw string literal, and then use a single backslash with regex escapes, or use a normal string literal and use double backslash with regex escapes (i.e. to define a single literal backslash).

Comment: here is my approach to do so
**m = re.sub(r'[0-9]{4}',re.findall(r'[0-9]{4}',content)[0]+",", content)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
import re

with open('pizza.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', r'\g<0>,', line))
```

See the Python demo:

```py
import re

content="""42/20/2021 every day is a good day 30.25
13/14/2015 today is saturday 24."""

for line in content.splitlines(False):
    print(re.sub(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', r'\g<0>,', line))
```

Output:

```
42/20/2021, every day is a good day 30.25
13/14/2015, today is saturday 24.
```

*Details*:

- `with open('pizza.txt', 'r') as f:` - opens the `pizza.txt` file for reading
- `for line in f:` -  reads the `f` file line by line
- `print(re.sub(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', r'\g<0>,', line))` - prints the result of the regex subsitution: `r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'` (mind the single backslashes in the raw string literal) finds all occurrences of two  digits, `/`, two digits, `/` and four digits and replaces with the same found value (the `\g<0>` backreference refers to the whole match value) and appends a comma right after.
  `