# How to import into pandas a file that is using a comma as delimiter but one of its columns has commas?

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that is separated by commas, but several columns have commas inside them so it creates columns where they are not needed. I have tried eliminating all the commas, then using regex to find only the numbers and add a comma (not worked) using the following solution ([Put comma after a pattern in python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891269/put-comma-after-a-pattern-in-python-regex)).

Excel has the same problem, and other text editors as well.

```
0111,Cultivo de cereales y otros cultivos n.c.p.,011,Cultivos en general; cultivo de productos de mercado; hortic,01,AGRICULTURA, GANADERIA, CAZA Y ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS CONE,01,**AGRICULTURA, GANADERIA, CAZA Y SILVICULTURA**
```

If you can see in the `**` text, Python will not create one column but 3.

Another solution would be to place " " marks, but I have not found a solution that creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data source is buggy. It should put quotes `" "` around such values, then pandas would be able to parse it. Without that, there is now no **reliable** logical way to tell the data apart now because the meaning of a comma now became ambiguous.

A **heuristic** solution could be to assume that any comma followed by a space should be removed while the others should be retained, you could try that, but there can still be cases in which it may fail.

```py
data.replace(", ", " ")
```